# Removing a row in autoincremented table and relate it with ListBox in C# MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

I've got a problem with relating deleted item in MySQL database with listbox.

I've got a Delete Form in C#, which contains listbox, and this contains names of futbol teams.

Now I'd like after selecting specific index in Listbox delete it from database and then, from Listbox 
Let's assume, that I've got 5 indexes ( 1,2,3,4,5 ). 
After deleting third record, records in database looks like that ( 1,2,4,5 ), but Listbox indexes are ( 1,2,3,4 ).

I've tried something like this: at every single connect to DB, copy indexes from Database to index of listbox, but there is a problem, when it comes to missing (third) record. Database doesn't want to perform this operation.

```
Command = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);

MySqlDataReader mySqlReader;

mySqlReader = Command.ExecuteReader();

while (mySqlReader.Read()){
    string sName = mySqlReader.GetString("name") + " --- " + mySqlReader.GetString("season");
    listBoxData.Items.Insert((int.Parse(mySqlReader.GetString("TeamID")) - 1), sName); // -1 because DB is Incrementing from 1, but listbox from 1.
}
```

May I ask for help, how I can solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: you should store an ID for each record in the database and include that in you Listbox (hide it if you want) and use that for deletion purpose.

Comment: I do it. I store every, single ID of team in my database. Problem is with Listbox right here ( I think so ), which doesn't accept gaps in Items.Index(?)

Comment: Sorry I was thinking ListView, in a list box you have a DisplayMember and ValueMember, set the ValueMember to the ID, and the DisplayMember to the string you want to show. When they click on an item get the ValueMember to delete from the DB.

Comment: added an example...

Comment: Don't use the index position of the item in the listbox as your key. That's not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate you list box do something like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select from teams...", conn);
adapter.Fill(ds);
this.listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
this.listBox1.ValueMember = "TeamID";
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "season";
```

Then when you are ready to delete:

```
var teamID = this.listBox1.SelectedValue;
//never do this make it a parameter!!
var sql = "delete from teams where TeamID = " + teamID.ToString();
```

Comment: Wow. It works, I couldn't find solution how it would look by using ValueMember and DisplayMember. Now everything works great. Thank you very much for your effort! Have a nice day